# How much data to send via TCP/IP at once

Tags: tcp, client-server, boost-asio, packet, throughput

I've written a small program with the boost asio library to transfer files via TCP from a server to one or more clients.

During testing I found out that the transfer is extremely slow, about 10KiB/s. Nagle's algorithm is already disabled. If I transfer the same file via FileZilla from the same server to the same client, I get about 280KiB/s, so obviously something was very wrong.

My approach so far was to fragment each file into smaller packets of 1024 bytes, send one fragment(each fragment=1 async_write-call) to the client and wait for the client's response. I need to fragment the data to allow the client to keep track of the download progress and speed. In retrospect I suppose this was rather naïve, because the server has to wait for the client's response after each fragment. To check if this was the bottleneck, I've increased the fragment size twice, giving me the following results:

```
a) Fragment Size: 1024bytes
Transfer Speed: ~10KiB/s
b) Fragment Size: 8192bytes
Transfer Speed: ~80KiB/s
c) Fragment Size: 20000bytes
Transfer Speed: ~195KiB/s
```

The results speak for themselves, but I'm unsure what to do now.

I'm not too familiar with how the data transfer is actually handled internally, but if I'm not mistaken all of my data is basically added onto a stream? If that's the case, do I need to worry about how much data I write to that stream at once? Does it make a difference at all whether I use multiple write-calls with small fragments as opposed to one write-call with a large fragment? Are there any guidelines for this?

Comment: Get rid of the acknowledgement and raise your buffer size to at least 32k.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply stream the data to the client without artificial packetization. Reenable nagling, this is not a scenario that calls for disabling it. It will cause small inefficiencies to have it disabled.

Typical write buffer sizes would be 4KB and above.

The client can issue read calls to the network one after the other. After each successful read the client will have a new estimation for the current progress that is quite accurate. Typically, there will be one succeeding read call for each network packet received. If the incoming rate is very high then multiple packets tend to be coalesced into one read. That's not ap roblem.

> If that's the case, do I need to worry about how much data I write to that stream at once?

No. Just keep a write call outstanding at all times.